Nest Power Connector (C Wire) on A/C unit GMP075-4
I’m trying to use a Nest thermostat on my older Goodman GMP075-4 unit. I have a Y, R, W, and G connector for the thermostat. I’ve read through a few number of the other questions related to this on the site. It looks like I’ll need to follow this diagram from Google since the board has no common wire port:

It looks like I’ll need to splice into the red and blue wires coming from my transformer like above (please don’t yell at me for placing power connector on the common like that, was just testing):  and 
The W and R ports were spliced into the following locations per the wiring diagram:


Though, still not getting power. After a few tries (15min - hour), it’ll kick on but with low power

This is when the unit is off, looks more reasonable 
Any ideas on what to try next? I confirmed with a multi meter that the places at the thermostat are getting 28v

Your question says "A/C" but you seem to have a furnace and no A/C.  You've correctly identified the Blue/White side of the transformer as a point of connection for C, but how are you getting that to the thermostat?  The yellow thermostat wire appears unused ... is that right? Because you have no A/C?  In that case this should be easy.  How are you connecting things?

VtC b/c it needs details, has no unique value and seems to have been abandoned by OP.

where's "C"
It's the blue wire in the first picture.
It also connects to the equipment ground. via that wire that goes under one of the transformer's mounting screws.
There's also a white wire (that should be a blue wire, and have a proper connector) connected to the transformwers C terminal.
